# Função strip() em python mau funcionamento

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, funções, selenium-webdriver

Tenho uma lista em um arquivo, onde cada linha possui um user agent (com " no início e no final de cada linha), que seŕa utilizado numa parte posterior de um programa, para realização de testes automatizados utilizando selenium.
Ao abrir a lista, implementei que, a cada linha lida, retiraria o primeiro e o último caractere de cada linha como segue:

```
USER_AGENTS_FILE = './users.txt'
RUNNING = True
    def LoadUserAgents(uafile=USER_AGENTS_FILE):
    uas = [ ]
    with open(uafile, 'rb' ) as uaf:
        for ua in uaf.readlines():
            if ua:
                uas.append(ua.strip()[1:-1-1])
    random.shuffle(uas)
    return uas 
uas = LoadUserAgents()
```

Adicionando também a funcionalidade de escolher aleatoriamente as linhas.
Porém, quando tento exibir a lista pelo seguinte comando:

```
for i in range(0,10):
print(random.choice(uas))
```

Obtenho algo como o seguinte:

```
 b'Mozilla/5.0 (BeOS; U; BeOS BePC; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070731 BonEcho/2.0.0.'
```

Quando na verdade, precisaria obter:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (BeOS; U; BeOS BePC; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070731 BonEcho/2.0.0.
```

alguém poderia me auxiliar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua string está em formato de bytes, e só precisa ser decodificada a um formato padrão.

```
>>> s =  b'Mozilla/5.0 (BeOS; U; BeOS BePC; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070731 BonEcho/2.0.0.'
>>> s.decode("utf-8")
'Mozilla/5.0 (BeOS; U; BeOS BePC; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070731 BonEcho/2.0.0.'
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!/
Obrigado pela ajuda!